# How can i randomly call a movieclip do something?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random

My stage have 3 movieclip that is mc1,mc2 and mc3.

each of them are now alpha=0.

I have a button on stage too and when click on it, 1 of the movieclip will be change to alpha=1.

here is my script:

```
var mcArray:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3];
for (var j:int = 0; j < hotSpot.length; j++)
{
    mcArray[j].alpha=0;
}

revealBtn.buttonMode = true;
    revealBtn.useHandCursor = false;
    revealBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, revealClick);
function revealClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
//what i need to write here?
}
```

Comment: -1 Have you even thought about it? Tried something? Or do you want the good people of StackOverflow to do everything for you? Even writing a simple program flow logic would have given you a clue. an example would be; Generate random Number between 0 and 2 (call it `i`) -> select ith element of mcArray -> change alpha of that element to 1.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I don't believe that is a reason to downvote a question. I'm going to +1 to cancel out your downvote.

Comment: @Taurayi: This is what pissed me off: "//what i need to write here?"...Such things first need to be tried, then you ask on SO. SO is not some place where you expect others to tell you what code to write without any effort from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending my comment to the question, here's what you would do step by step:

```
//Generate random number (integer) between 0 and mcArray.length
var i:Number=Math.floor(Math.random() * mcArray.length);

//Select ith element of mcArray
var movieClipToEdit:MovieClip=mcArray[i] as MovieClip;

//Change its alpha to 1
movieClipToEdit.alpha=1;
```

If you want to hide all other movie clips, add this:

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < mcArray.length; j++) {
    mcArray[j].alpha=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how to show a random display object after clicking the stage:

**Main.as(document class)**:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sprites:Vector.<Sprite>;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sprites = new Vector.<Sprite>();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
                sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                sprite.graphics.endFill();
                sprite.x = ((sprite.width + 50) * i);
                sprite.y = 0;
                addChild(sprite);

                _sprites.push(sprite);

            }// end for

            hideSprites();

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        }// end function

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            showSprite();

        }// end function

        private function showSprite():void
        {
            hideSprites();

            (_sprites[random(0, 2)] as Sprite).alpha = 1;

        }// end function

        private function hideSprites():void
        {
            for each(var sprite:Sprite in _sprites)
            {
                sprite.alpha = 0;

            }// end for each

        }// end function

        private function random(min:int, max:int):int
        {
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + max - min)) +min); 

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Simply put, you use `Math.round()` to get a random index for your display object array, in this example that happens here:

```
(_sprites[random(0, 2)] as Sprite).alpha = 1;

private function random(min:int, max:int):int
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + max - min)) +min); 

}// end function
```

You can also replace the value for the `random()` method's `max` argument with `_sprites.length - 1` which will also return 2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not familiar with class, the answer below is more suitable for my code now.BTW, thanks for helping up, I hope your code can help others people :)